# Interpret string as escaped string

Tags: javascript, escaping, unicode-escapes

Why doesn't this work?

```
decodeURI('\n') => newline;
decodeURI("\\n") => '\n', thus presumably...
decodeURI(decodeURI("\\n")) // => gives '\n' instead of newline
```

But this does?

```
JSON.parse('"\\n"') // => newline
```

Point here is to be able to build a \* character string, then convert it to its actual character via decodeURI.

I'd like to avoid using JSON.parse if possible.

## EDIT

I realize the way I approached this was confusing. A better question would have been to ask how decodeURI and JSON.parse do their conversion from the string literal to the resolved character and if there was something more direct.

Comment: Because `\n` is not URI encoding.

Comment: @SLaks - I added another line for clarification.

Comment: "*I'd like to avoid using JSON.parse if possible.*" - but why? It's the function that you need, it's the function that works.

Comment: After your edit, the question still doesn't make any sense at all. URL encoding doesn't involve `\*`.

Comment: You should start by understanding what [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decodeURI('\n') => newline; thus presumably
```

In your code, `\n` is a newline character *before it even gets to decodeURI*.  Backslashes have meaning in a string literal in JavaScript.

```
decodeURI(decodeURI("\\n")) // => gives '\n' instead of newline
```

In this example, you've escaped the backslash with another backslash.  Therefore, instead of passing a newline character to `decodeURI()`, you're passing the text of a backslash character and an 'n' character.  Neither of these have special meaning in URIs and thus the output of this `decodeURI()` is the same as its input.  Doing it twice of course makes zero difference.  I don't really follow what your point is here.

> But this does?
>
> `JSON.parse('"\\n"') // => newline`

Again, try to unpack it is what you're doing here.  The first backslash escapes the next, leaving you with an actual backslash in the string.  So, the real string is `"\n"`.  If you `JSON.parse()` this, the parser first interprets that you're dealing with a string literal.  Then, it decodes `\n` to a newline character.  That's why it outputs just a newline.

> Point here is to be able to build a * character string, then convert it to its actual character via decodeURI.

`decodeURI` has absolutely nothing to do with that.

Comment: I get that decodeURI isn't meant for this and that I should use JSON.parse. I'm basically asking for the ability to build these escaped characters directly, without needing JSON.parse, which interprets it.

Comment: @Karric To re-emphasize what I wrote in my answer, a newline character has zero meaning to `decodeURI()`.  If you want a newline out of `decodeURI()` (and, you shouldn't), just pass a newline into it, exactly as you do in your very first line of example code.  I recommended reading up on some basic syntax of JavaScript and fully understanding this before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason that this:

```
decodeURI(decodeURI("\\n"));
```

Doesn't give a newline, yet this does:

```
JSON.parse('"\\n"');
```

It's because `\n` is not actually a URI component (if a newline were URI encoded, it'd look like `%0A` rather than `\n`), and also because it's actually escaped.

Here are some demonstrations:

---

Demo 1: `decodeURI("\n")`:

```js
var newline = decodeURI("\n");
console.log("Line One" + newline + "Line Two");
```

You can see in the above that there is a newline in the console, between `Line One` and `Line Two`.

---

Demo 2: `decodeURI(decodeURI("\\n"))`:

```js
var newline = decodeURI(decodeURI("\\n"));
console.log("Line One" + newline + "Line Two");
```

Here, we can see that the escaped newline (`\\n`) when decoded is just a newline string - `newline` *literally* is the string `"\n"`, not a newline. We can see proof of this in the next demonstration:

---

Demo 3: `typeof decodeURI("\\n")`:

```js
var newline = decodeURI("\\n");
console.log("Line One" + newline + "Line Two");
console.log(typeof newline);
```

And here we see that `decodeURI("\\n")` returns just a string `\n`, which for reasons unknown cannot be decoded by using `decodeURI` twice, as you'll see here:

---

Demo 4: `decodeURI(decodeURI("\\n"))`:

```js
var newline = decodeURI("\\n");
var temp = decodeURI(newline);
console.log("Line One" + newline + "Line Two");
newline = temp;
console.log("Line One" + newline + "Line Two");
```

And here we can see that `newline` and `temp` are pretty much the same thing - the string `"\n"`.

---

There is a reason that this code:

```
decodeURI("\n");
```

Actually returns a newline character as well - it is because before `decodeURI` is used, `"\n"` is already a newline character, so `decodeURI` is redundant. See this:

```js
var newlineString = "\n";
var newline = decodeURI(newlineString);
console.log("Line One" + newlineString + "Line Two");
console.log("Line One" + newline + "Line Two");
```

Here, both lines are separated by line breaks, which means that `"\n"` doesn't actually get decoded at all - you don't need `decodeURI` for this at all.

---

Hopefully this helps you!

---

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI
- [Escaping backslash in string - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618374/escaping-backslash-in-string-javascript)
- [Escape new lines with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921319/escape-new-lines-with-js)